# Distance Matrix in k-prototypes clustMixType

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

Hi everyone I am trying to obtain a distance matrix when using clustMixType R package. Specifically when using the function kproto(x, ...), the output gives me a column called "cluster" which is the Vector of cluster memberships and other columns called dists.(i) [Matrix with distances of observations to all cluster prototypes] where i is the number of resulting clusters, like the following data frame:

```
#        cluster        dists.1     dists.2    dists.3
#1       1             0.04763169  0.6398194  0.75879754
#2       1             1.65313658  1.3228020  0.31168919
#3       2             0.47583030  0.6636173  0.03983268
#4       ..             ...         ...        ...
```

but, in my knowledge this is not a Distance matrix like:

```
[
    [0, 2, 3],
    [2, 0, 4],
    [3, 4, 0] ]
```

I want to know if it is possible to derive the Distance Matrix from the R output

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `dist` to compute a pairwise distance matrix.

`kproto` performs prototype clustering. It probably does not use pairwise distances, only to prototypes.

Comment: Thank you, but the `dist` function does not computes the following distance that is used in `kproto` d(x,y)=d{euclid}(x,y)+lambda*d{simple matching}(x,y)

Comment: Then write a function that does so? Is not difficult, is it?

Comment: Yeah thank you that is the solution I will try to do so.